# add helpers to static pages and layouts

Tags: cakephp

Can I add a `helper` to my static page (for example my homepage) and layouts?
How? (Because no actions are available. In `PagesContoller.php`, we've `display` action. I add a `home` action, but it is overridden by `display` action)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a Helper in every controller and layout you can load in AppController.php:

```
<?php
    class AppController extends Controller {
          public $helpers = array('Form', 'Html', 'Js', 'Time', 'MyCustomHelper');
    }
 ?>
```

Your `home` action will not work because of the default settings in `Config/routes.php`:

```
 Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

Any passed argument to /pages/ is sent to the `display` action. Either create a new route for functions in PagesController or create a new controller.

Example route to get PagesController functions to work:

```
    Router::connect('/pages/show/:action/*', array('controller' => 'pages'));
```

(Place this route **before** your `/pages/*` route!)